# Windows phone 7 messageBox sound

Tags: windows-phone-7

Is there any way to disable the sound that sounds when a messageBox shows?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a way - you have to show the MessageBox using XNA

There are a few articles around -

- http://www.danielmoth.com/Blog/GuideBeginShowMessageBox-Wrapper.aspx (thanks for the link from [@mrlacey](http://twitter.com/mrlacey)/[@wpug](http://twitter.com/wpug))
- http://dotnet.dzone.com/articles/delivering-message-using

You need to play with the MessageBoxIcon method:

> MessageBoxIcon is in fact not an icon (yeah, I know - the name says so). On Windows Phone 7, it will define the short sound that will accompany the message. And here you have several choices: Alert, None, Error, Warning

However, be warned that using the XNA methods is slightly awkward as they are non-blocking methods (and you may also have to look at how they interact with the back button too)

Some people have also written their own messagebox - e.g. http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/tomershamam/archive/2010/10/19/windows-phone-7-custom-message-box.aspx

Comment: is this the link you were after http://www.danielmoth.com/Blog/GuideBeginShowMessageBox-Wrapper.aspx

Comment: One hint for the marketplace acceptance - make sure that the popup is cleared when you press the back button.

Comment: Yeah, too bad I did not see this before I submitted it! It got rejected because if did not clear.But it has since been accepted.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

At this time, there is no way for the user to disable this sound and there is no way as a developer to disable this sound either.